# How to apply normal-, gloss-, occlusion-, specularity- and displacement map on one cycles material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I try to apply all these textures to one material in cycles.
These are all my textures:

[image: textures]

My attempt (no idea at all how occlusion map works)

[image: attempt]

Answer (score 2):

It can't be said exactly as it depends on the setup/program they were baked out of in the first place. But in general:

**Color:** Diffuse Node Color

**Normal:** Diffuse and Gloss Normal input. Put into Normal node first if you want control of it.

**Displace:** Bump node, then Diffuse and Gloss Normal input. When you also have a normal map, plug the normal map into the Bump node's normal input. It can also go in the material output Displacement socket. This is necessary if trying to use True Displacement. But generally not needed.

**Gloss:** This is either the Glossy Node's color or Roughness. If it is the roughness, the color should be pure white.

**Spec:** This is the mix fac between Diffuse and Gloss. It can be combined with Fresnel for added realism (the details for how to do this vary.) Note that in some cases, Gloss and Spec are reversed.

**Occlusion:** This can mean several things, so it also varies. It could be Roughness, or it could be multiplied over Diffuse and Gloss color, or it could be a mix fac between Diffuse and black AO node, or a color for AO with an unknown mix fac with Diffuse. Or it could not be needed at all due to Cycles having global illumination. AO is generally for faking some aspects of ambient light in game engines that don't actually have real indirect lighting.

If you can give more info on where the maps came from, or share the whole file, then we can narrow it down more for this specific case.