# How do I use albedo, heightmap and normalmap on a material?

Tags: texturing

I've been going through a couple of tutorials on applying textures using the node editor, but I can't seem to get it right. I downloaded some 3d images, they include (albedo, heightmap and normalmap) but that's as far as I can go. I don't know how I should apply them. While following a tutorial it seems so easy but now that I'm trying it by myself, things get a bit tricky :p. I've already UV unwraped my mesh, now I just need some sort of guideline. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55232/how-to-properly-hook-up-various-maps-types-together-in-cycles   and here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80695/how-to-apply-normal-gloss-occlusion-specularity-and-displacement-map-on-o

This question should probably be marked as a duplicate unless you can post a specific file/set of textures, then I can answer you on how to use that particular combination.

Comment: @Drudge you can flag it as a duplicate by clicking on flag

Comment: I've just gone through the links. There are so helpful. Thank you!! You are actually right. This question is actually a duplicate now that I've seen the two links above. I'll go ahead and flag it as a duplicate.