# help understanding purpose of downloaded textures

Tags: texturing

I downloaded a sonic model from sketchfab and added all the textures, then checked the other things that came with it, many where images that seemed to have something to do with the textures, but I'm not really sure what they're exactly supposed to do

[image: the images]

Here's the link for the model: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/sonic-hd-full-rigged-65cc641a3adf42468641cc208a858187

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174401/how-do-i-use-texture-maps-in-cycles-nodes?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80695/how-to-apply-normal-gloss-occlusion-specularity-and-displacement-map-on-o and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120623/how-to-apply-albedo-ambient-occlusion-normal-bump-maps-and-metalic-roughness-t/120627#120627